# How to sum List<int> values but only by cells in C#?

Tags: c#, linq

For example I have this as `List<List<int>>`:

```
[2,4,4,2,5]
[1,3,6,3,8]
[0,3,9,0,0]
```

Should return the sum but only taking cells assuming that the cell count is **always** the same:

```
[3, 10, 19, 5, 13]
```

I am trying to find an easy way to solve this using `Linq` if it is possible because I am doing this with a lot of `for` loops and `if` conditions and I am complicating myself.

Is there  a possible way to achieve this using Linq?

Comment: The data you have shown is not a List<Int>, but looks more like a List of lists.  Can you please clarify.  Also, show how you have done it today.

Comment: Are you saying, without actually saying, that you have a `List<List<int>>` or maybe a `List<int[]>` and you want to create a new list or array where the values at each index are the sums of the values at the same index in the original lists or arrays?

Comment: Sorry it is *List<List<int>>*

Comment: Show us your current, working code. Maybe that can be simplified and then you'll be able to write equivalent LINQ code yourself.

Comment: Either you have an understanding of LINQ or you don't. If you don't, you need to make an effort to learn; it's not for us to just write your code for you. If you do have an understanding then you need to make your best attempt to come up with a solution and specify where exacly you're stuck or what you have doesn't work. If you haven;t tried anything then you don;t have a problem to ask about on SO.

Comment: As a clue, `Enumerable.Range` might be useful. It can be used to generate a list of indexes into an array or list that can then be used later in a query, e.g. `var arr2 = Enumerable.Range(0, arr1.Length).Select(i => arr1[i] + 1).ToArray()`.

Comment: *"Is there a possible way to achieve this using Linq?"*. Yes there is. Is it necessarily better than using a loop? Not really, if you don't understand LINQ well enough to write it. Don't assume that LINQ is inherently better in every case. It can lead to more succinct code but it's not going to mroe maintainable if you don;t understand it properly. There's nothing wrong with loops.

Comment: I am asking if it is a short way to achieve this cause my code is a mess and buggy so that is why I am asking for help from the experts

Comment: Why you're asking doesn't really matter. Yes there is a short way but, despite the fact that some people have chosen to do so, it's not the purpose of this site to just write your code for you. If your existing code is a mess and buggy then you should be asking a question about that. It sounds like you don't understand the logic involved so you shouldn't even be thinking about LINQ code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linq approach

```
List<List<int>> items = new List<List<int>>() {
                        new List<int> { 2, 4, 4, 2, 5 },
                        new List<int> { 1, 3, 6, 3, 8 },
                        new List<int> { 0, 3, 9, 0, 0 } };

List<int> result = Enumerable.Range(0, items.Min(x => x.Count)).Select(x => items.Sum(y => y[x])).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var xx = new List<List<int>>() {
    new List<int>() { 2, 4, 4, 2, 5 },
    new List<int>() { 1, 3, 6, 3, 8 },
    new List<int>() { 0, 3, 9, 0, 0 },
};
var y = xx.Aggregate((r, x) => r.Zip(x).Select(p => p.First + p.Second).ToList());
```

Answer (score 2):

> I am doing this with a lot of `for` loops and `if` conditions and I am complicating myself.

You can accomplish it by using a single `for` loop.

Two possible approaches to achieve that are:

**Approach 1**

1. Creating an array with a capacity equal to the size of either of the lists in the original list collection
2. Filling the array with `0`s
3. Looping through all lists in the original list collection, aggregating the sum for each index

**Approach 2**

1. Creating a list based on the first list in the original list collection
2. Looping through all *subsequent* lists in the original list collection, aggregating the sum for each index

Both approaches benefit from the assumption given in the question post:

> [...] assuming that the cell count is **always** the same

---

If your original list collection is defined as a `List<List<int>>`:

```csharp
List<List<int>> valuesCollection = new()
{
    new() { 2, 4, 4, 2, 5 },
    new() { 1, 3, 6, 3, 8 },
    new() { 0, 3, 9, 0, 0 },
};
```

, the two approaches may be implemented as follows:

**Approach 1**

```csharp
var indexCount = valuesCollection[0].Count;

var sums = new int[indexCount];
Array.Fill(sums, 0);

foreach (var values in valuesCollection)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < sums.Length; i++)
    {
        sums[i] += values[i];
    }
}
```

**Approach 2**

- Note: Uses namespace `System.Linq`

```csharp
var sums = valuesCollection[0].ToList();

foreach (var values in valuesCollection.Skip(1))
{
    for (var i = 0; i < sums.Count; i++)
    {
        sums[i] += values[i];
    }
}
```

Using either approach, `sums`'s resulting content will be `{ 3, 10, 19, 5, 13 }`.

---

Example fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/umXlpa).